# flag/close reasons: trollery?

Tags: discussion

the reason I want to flag/close a question is because it is simply incoherent, and possibly the work of a troll. but none of the options available cover this.  can we add something along these lines as a reason?

Comment: What about coherent trollery?

Comment: You have asked a series of meta questions that are hard to answer because you don't give enough information. Please provide links when you ask about specific posts. Also, be concrete and precise. "simply incoherent" needs examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this needs to be a basic reason to close precisely because this is a reason to flag, but maybe others take a different view?

I personally would:

1. Vote to close as "unclear what you're asking"
2. Flag for moderator intervention.